# Mysql many to many query

Tags: sql, mysql

Having a mental block with going around this query.

I have the following tables:

**review_list**: has most of the data, but in this case the only important thing is review_id, the id of the record that I am currently interested in (int) 
**variant_list**: model (varchar), enabled (bool)
**variant_review**: model (varchar), id (int)

variant_review is a many to many table linking the review_id in review_list to the model(s) in variant_list review and contains (eg):

```
..  
test1,22
test2,22
test4,22
test1,23
test2,23... etc
```

variant_list is a list of all possible models and whether they are enabled and contains (eg):

```
test1,TRUE
test2,TRUE
test3,TRUE
test4,TRUE
```

what I am after in mysql is a query that when given a review_id (ie, 22) will return a resultset that will list each value in variant_review.model, and whether it is present for the given review_id such as:

```
test1,1
test2,1
test3,0
test4,1
```

or similar, which I can farm off to some webpage with a list of checkboxes for the types. This would show all the models available and whether each one was present in the table

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are looking for. It doesnt hurt to be verbose. Something like the schema for each table would go miles towards helping you find a solution. And what the two values of your desired result set are...

Comment: It'd be helpful if you enumerate the columns being displayed in your sample data and sample output.

Comment: Sorry for the dodgy question, have updated it to provide a clearer question and example data in and out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a bit more information about the column names:

```
Select variant_list.model
    , Case When variant_review.model Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End As HasReview
From variant_list
    Left join variant_review
        On variant_review.model = variant_list.model
            And variant_review.review_id = 22
```

Just for completeness, if it is the case that you can have multiple rows in the `variant_review` table with the same model and review_id, then you need to do it differently:

```
Select variant_list.model
    , Case 
        When Exists (
                    Select 1
                    From variant_review As VR
                    Where VR.model = variant_list.model
                        And VR.review_id = 22
                    ) Then 1
        Else 0
        End 
From variant_list
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I think my question was wrong. I have updated the question to make it clear what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @Woody - I've revised my solution. This will get you all values from variant_list and if there is a value for the given review_id. I'm assuming that the combination of model and review_id can only appear once in the variant_review table (i.e. you cannot have two rows with the same values for both model and review_id).

Comment: The first one is good, the combination should never be able to appear again.
Thanks very much, has saved me lots of hassle!